# Ways to represent $ n=\pm1^2 \pm2^2 \pm \dots \pm k^2, $ (Erdos-Suranyi?)

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory

> Prove that for every $n\in\mathbb{N}$ there are infinitely many ways
>   to represent $n$ as $$ n=*1^2*2^2*\dots*k^2, $$ where
>   $k\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $*\in\{+,-\}$.

On my paper, this problem is marked as "Erdos-Suranyi", but I could find anything about it on Google.

Comment: RE: "On my paper".. is this a `(homework)` question?

Comment: There's no need to use `\large` here. Also, I edited your title to make it self-contained; please check that I didn't change your meaning.

Comment: In any case, you just need to find *one* way to represent $n$ as a sum and difference of squares, and then you can always add $a^2+b^2-c^2$ for any Pythagorean triple $(a,b,c)$ to get infinitely many different representations.

Comment: It is unclear whether one can add or subtract *any* squares, or if *every* square from $1^2$ through some $k^2$ must appear in the expression.

Comment: @J.D. It's not homework, it's on the paper for preparing for national competition, we couldn't manage to do it on class few weeks ago so it was left undone on my paper.

Comment: I suspect that notation simply means that the problem (or the result) can be found in *Topics in the Theory of Numbers*, by Erdős and Surányi.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The classic solution to show existence of one solution is to use the identity

$$ (n+3)^2 - (n+2)^2 - (n+1)^2 + n^2 = 4$$

and the fact that $1,2,3,4$ have a representation:

$$1 = + 1^2$$
$$2 = - 1^2 - 2^2 - 3^2 + 4^2$$
$$3 = -1^2 + 2^2$$
$$4 = -1^2 - 2^2 + 3^2$$

To get one representation of $4m+r$, we inductively get one representation for $4(m-1) + r$, and use the above identity.

Now, as Andre pointed out, given one representation we can extend that to infinitely many representations by writing $0+0+0 \dots$ as $(4 - 4) + (4-4) + (4-4) \dots$ and using the above identity multiple times.